# The wicket Panel doesn't get refresh on button submit

Tags: java, refresh, wicket

I need to refresh the panel (it has been declared as panel in the below code) after I add a new group. The `ItemSelectionComponent` component is a different `Panel` that contains the added groups of a particular person. What I need to do is once I add a new group that particular panel (the `ItemSelectionComponent` panel with the wicket id `"panel"`) should be refreshed and the newly added group should get displayed. 
I currently use 
`target.addComponent(panel);`
to refresh, but it doesn't seems to be working :(

Can someone tell me whats wrong? 
thanks!

Comment: Does your ItemSelectionComponent contain a ListView?

Comment: show us the code that displays the groups

Comment: Added the code for ItemSelectionComponent

Comment: instead of RepeatingView, you should use a RefreshingView.

Comment: you can try setResponsePage(CurrentPage.class) on submit

Comment: hmm i wonder if its because your using a submit. I've had problems before mixing ajax and a form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your avaiableGroups should be a LoadableDetachableModel that contains your list of GroupSelectionModels. When you use the AjaxSubmitLink get List from the LoadableDetachableModel and add to it.

```
LoadableDetachableModel<List<GroupSelectionModel>> LDM = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<GroupSelectionModel>>() {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Override
     protected String load() {                          
           return ServiceLocator.getInstance().find(GroupService.class).getAllGroups();;
     }
};


AjaxSubmitLink addBtn = new AjaxSubmitLink("addBtn") {

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> f) {

            List<Group> currentGroups = ServiceLocator.getInstance().find(GroupService.class).getAllGroups();
            Group group = new Group();
            group.setGroupType(Group.GroupType.EMAIL);
            group.setMerchant(merchant);
            group.setGroupName(form.getModelObject().getGroupName());


            ServiceLocator.getInstance().find(GroupService.class).saveGroup(group);
            GroupSelectionModel newGroup = new GroupSelectionModel();
            newGroup.setGroup(group);
            newGroup.setGroupSelected(true);
            LDM.getObject().add(newGroup);
    target.addComponent(panel);
        }
    };
```

Then pass LDM as a param to ItemSelectionComponent instead of avaiableGroups. Use LDM in ItemSelectionComponent like you did avaiableGroups.

```
 public class ItemSelectionComponent extends Panel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6670144847L;
private LoadableDetachableModel<List<GroupSelectionModel>> model;

public ItemSelectionComponent(String id,LoadableDetachableModel<List<GroupSelectionModel>> model){
    super(id);
    this.model = model;
    init();

}

private void init(){
    WebMarkupContainer groupSelectionContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("groupSelectionContainer");
    RepeatingView repeater = new RepeatingView("groupList");
    WebMarkupContainer groupList;

    for(final GroupSelectionModel m : model.getObject()){
        groupList = new WebMarkupContainer(repeater.newChildId());
        WebMarkupContainer groupNameContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("groupNameContainer");
        groupNameContainer.add(new Label("groupName", m.getGroup().getGroupName()));
        groupList.add(groupNameContainer);
        repeater.add(groupList);                  
    }
    groupSelectionContainer.add(repeater);
    this.add(groupSelectionContainer);
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this out but no much luck, still when i add a new group if doesn't get displayed in the panel after the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I have one possible solution to your problem.
Add a **WebMarkupContainer**:

```
final WebMarkupContainer panelContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("panelContainer");
panelContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

And in the html you will have it as:

```
<div wicket:id="panelContainer"></div>
```

Then you must add the panel to your markup container:

```
panelContainer.add(panel)
```

And add the markup container on the target instead of the panel:

```
target.addComponent(panelContainer);
```

If this doesn't work let me know and i will provide further assitance

Answer (score 0):

When you target the panel the components in it will be refreshed. But what happens depends on how "ItemSelectionComponent" is using "avaiableGroups".

Comment: The problem is this code `for(final GroupSelectionModel m : model.getObject())`. This only runs once, when you create the panel, and then you never pull anything new out of the model again. Use a ListView with the model as the source instead of a RepeatingView. Then the values will be fetched from the model each time the panel is targeted.